# record audio but save it if it has data on android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am recording audio on android but the main issue I am facing right now is that I don't want to save audio file if audio has no data in it (like the user has said nothing). I can save it then check the time or length of the audio file and then delete it, but I want to check it before storing file to reduce the work and improve performance.

Comment: Detecting if audio has a meaningful voice or a noise is very complicated process. You should find out if audio noise in it or not. This goes to subject of audio processing. You should look for how to detect meaningful audio from any audio file extracting noise or weak audio signals.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @FredrickGauss yes I agree with you that it is a very complicated process. But its like I don't want my app to process every single audio that has nothing in it as data. So let me try extraction and let's see how it works. Thanks for the hint btw

Comment: @AD10 I don't think you need my code you understand my problem, as I am not facing any problem in my code but I asked about the approaches that anyone might have used to do want I am thinking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on ambient noise, checking the amplitude may not be enough. You may need to do a Fast Fourrier transform on the audio to separate the frequencies. This can be done with a minimal amount of buffering.

See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) for a visual explanation of what a Fourrier Transform is. There is [also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r18Gi8lSkfM) this video. It's actually a super fascinating topic.

In any case, there is sample code for an audio visualizer in the following [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232676). Here is the accompanying [github site](https://github.com/apress/pro-android-media) for that book. It may also contain some other audio-related code samples you may find useful.

Comment: I liked the videos though but unfortunately, I am unable to see any implementation of this on android. The link you shared has the different context than what I asked. So if you can share any implementation on android related to my question context than please do let me know.

Comment: @CodeHunter, Sorry, I linked to the wrong FFT code. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the amplitude of the voice stream on **MediaRecorder** by :

```
public double getAmplitude() {
    if (recorder != null)
        return  recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

then you can check the range to detect if there is any valuable data (like talking) on the audio or not

Comment: @CodeHunter : as Fredrick mentioned in his comment , audio processing is too complicated to find out that its meaningful, so with this solution you can just check that if there is any audio amplitude change occurred or not, in noisy places max amplitude returns you higher numbers so detecting audio change range is more difficult